# MySQL: select list of unique "name" order by DESC

Tags: mysql

how to select list of unique "name" order by id DESC, limit 5

user table structure:

```
id      name
1       John      
2       John
3       Andrew
4       John
5       Sarah
6       dan
7       Sarah
8       Simon
9       Sarah
10      John
```

expcted results

```
name:
John
Sarah
Simon
dan
Andrew
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this is the easiest way to do it:

```
select name from table_name
group by name
order by max(id) desc
limit 5
```

No joins needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it

```
select t1.name from table_name t1 
left join table_name t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.id < t2.id 
where t2.id is null 
order by t1.id desc limit 5 ;
```

Comment: skipping name ? can you give me an example ? Since the idea is to get all the unique names order by the id and then limit.

Comment: sorry, it isn't really skipping, but result not correctly sorted by "id" DESC

Comment: Sorry my bad `t1.id > t2.id ` should be `t1.id < t2.id `

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name from ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT name 
  FROM nameTable 
  ORDER BY id DESC
)
```

Comment: should it be "ASC" or "DESC" ?

Comment: From your table I'd say ASC

Comment: I want to return latest

Comment: The `ORDER` in the inner query doesn't guarantee this order is used in the outer query. So this might "seem" to work in a small test, but don't rely on it.